# Determining all the subfields of the splitting field for $x^8-2$ which are Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, normal-subgroups

I have found all the subgroups of the Galois group of the splitting field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and I know that if any of the subgroups $H$ of $G=$Gal$(K/\mathbb{Q})$ are normal in $G$, then $H$ corresponds to a subfield of $K$ that is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.  There are $16$ subgroups here -- do I have to check each one individually for normality?  That seems like it would take ages, and I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: What is the Galois group?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is $G=$Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q})=\langle \sigma, \tau: \sigma^8=\tau^2=1, \sigma \tau=\tau\sigma^3\rangle$ for
$$\sigma : \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \theta\mapsto \theta\zeta\\
            \zeta \mapsto -\zeta=\zeta^5\\
            i\mapsto i
    
        \end{array},\;
    \right.
\tau : \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \theta\mapsto \theta\\
            \zeta \mapsto \zeta^7\\
            i \mapsto  - i
        \end{array},
    \right.$$
and $\zeta$ be a primative $8$th root of unity.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85172/fastest-way-to-compute-subfields-of-mathbbq-sqrt82-i-which-are-galois?rq=1) question seems very relevant. There are further useful links in the comments there.

Comment: Thanks.  In particular on your linked question is this wikipedia link [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_semidihedral_group:SD16) -- which is very helpful.  In case other people find this thread.