# Splitting field for $x^4-2\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am studying the splitting field for $x^4-2\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Let $F$ denote the splitting field for $x^4-2\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. I found that the Galois group of the extension $\mathbb{Q}\subset F$ is  $D_8.$ And since there are four proper normal subgroups of $D_8$ we can conclude that there are four subfields of $F.$ Four subgroups are following: trivial subgroup, $\mathbb{Z}_2$, Klein four group and $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Now I want to know which of these subfields are stable.

Definition of stable: if $E$ is an intermediate field of the extension $K\subset F$, $E$ is said to be stable (relative to $K$ and $F$) if every $K$-automorphism $\sigma\in Aut_KF$ maps $E$ into itself.

Then by the definition of stable, trivial subgroup and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are stable? Am I right?

Comment: You say the trivial group and $\mathbb Z_2$ are stable but defined stability for the intermediate field extensions.

Comment: @Dave I am sorry I didn't get what you mean. Can you explain little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: You've defined stability for the fields, so why are you saying that the groups $\mathbb Z_2$ and the trivial group are stable (i.e. what is stability for subgroups?)?

Comment: @Dave I see what you mean. If I want to find the subfields of $F$, should I look at the normal subgroups of the Galois group of the extension $\mathbb{Q}\subset F$? Source: <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85172/fastest-way-to-compute-subfields-of-mathbbq-sqrt82-i-which-are-galois?rq=1>

Comment: Sure; you want to find the subfields and analyse those. I guess it helps to first know what the splitting field is. Note that the roots of $x^4-2$ are $\pm i\sqrt[4]{2}$  and $\pm \sqrt[4]{2}$ (for a total of four roots).

Comment: @Dave Thanks for your comment. The Galois group is $D_8$ in this case. And the normal subgroups of $D_8$ are trivial subgroup, $\mathbb{Z}_2$, Klein four group and $\mathbb{Z}_4$. But then I don't know what are the subfields. How to find it from normal subgroups of $D_8$, and after finding it how to check whether it is stable or not? Sorry for too many questions.

Comment: You could try drawing the lattice structure for the subfields. So the top would be the whole splitting field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$, and then look at intermediate subfields of this (try examining the generators). Another way is to look at the subgroups of the Galois group and see what they do to the generators or roots of the splitting field.

Comment: Note that $D_8$ has two different (normal) subgroups isomorphic to Klein-four. Anyway, normal subgroups don't correspond one-to-one with subfields, they correspond one-to-one with *normal* subfields. $F$ has ten subfields (counting $F$ itself, and the rationals; eight, if you just want proper nontrivial subfields).

Comment: So, have you had a look at that link I gave, Sungn?