# Is the Galois group Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{8}}, i)/\mathbb{Q}(i))$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Is the Galois group Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{8}}, i)/\mathbb{Q}(i))$ cyclic?

I started by the fact that $x^8-2$ is the minimal polynomial. But then the $4th$ roots of unity are involved, so I am not sure how the extension is even galois. I must be making a mistake. Also, even if I could show that it is indeed a Galois extension, what's the best way to show that it is cyclic or not?

Comment: Perhaps first consider $\Bbb Q(2^{1/8},i) = \Bbb Q(2^{1/8},e^{2\pi i/8})$ as a Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$ (these Kummer fields might be more familiar) and decide which elements of that Galois group fix $\Bbb Q(i)$?

Comment: Could you please elaborate in an answer as to how these kinds of problems are tackled? I am very new to Galois theory, plus I have never heard of the Kummer fields. @GregMartin

Comment: Two hints. For showing the extension is Galois: $e^{2\pi i/8} = \cos(\pi/4) + i \sin(\pi/4) = \cdots$? For the rest: any Galois automorphism must send $\sqrt[8]{2}$ to another root of $x^8-2$, and specifying the image of $\sqrt[8]{2}$ uniquely determines such an automorphism.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85172/fastest-way-to-compute-subfields-of-mathbbq-sqrt82-i-which-are-galois?noredirect=1&lq=1) also shows what the normal subgroups are. Yours is a normal subgroup of order $8$. The Galois group itself, which is the one of $x^8-2$, has order $16$. All possibilities are listed [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_semidihedral_group:SD16). Now it is easy to find out yours, over $\Bbb Q(i)$.