# How to describe all normal subgroups of the dihedral group?

Tags: group-theory

I guess it's a group of rotations… How to describe it mathematically?

Comment: You'd probably be interested in this [related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917/finding-all-normal-subgroups-of-a-group?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the presentation
$$
D_n = \langle r, s \mid r^n = s^2 = (rs)^2=1 \rangle,
$$
in which $r$ is a generating rotation (you can think of it as a rotation through an angle $\frac{2 k \pi}{n}$, where $\gcd(n, k) = 1$) and $s$ is *any* reflection.  Note that the last relation is equivalent to $s r^{-1} = r s$.

The subgroup $\langle r \rangle$ of rotations of index $2$ is indeed normal (as are all index $2$ sucorrectbgroups, generally).  You should be able to show this by direct calculation, though.  **EDIT:  generally, the subgroup $\langle r^d \rangle$ for $d | n$ is also normal.**

Suppose that a normal subgroup includes a reflection.  **EDIT:  If $n$ is odd, then all of the reflections $r^ks~(0 \le k < n)$ are conjugate, so by including one in a *normal* subgroup, we include them all.  However, when $n$ is even, the reflections split into two conjugacy classes, and we get two more normal subgroups:  $\langle r^2, s \rangle$ and $\langle r^2, rs \rangle$.**  <strike>In this case, you can show that the subgroup is all of $D_n$.  Can you see how?</strike>

Comment: Dear Sammy: *Suppose that a normal subgroup includes a reflection. In this case, you can show that the subgroup is all of $D_n$.* I don't think he can: $\{1,r^2,s,r^2s\}$ is a normal subgroup of the dihedral group of 8 elements, for example. Regards

Comment: You are absolutely right, of course, @rschwieb.  I will edit my answer to correct this mistake.

Comment: OP:  I recommend that you deselect my answer, and choose the answer of @rschwieb.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\langle \sigma,\tau\mid\sigma^n=\tau^2=1,\tau\sigma=\sigma^{n-1}\tau\rangle$ be our picture of the dihedral group.

There is at least one class of normal subgroups that is easy to classify: all subgroups of the rotation group are normal. Let $\sigma^i$ be in any subgroup of the rotations $\langle\sigma\rangle$. The rotations are an abelian group, so obviously conjugation by any rotation leaves $\sigma^i$ in its subgroup. The only thing to check is whether or not congjugation by $\tau$ leaves it in its subgroup. But an easy computation shows that $\tau\sigma^i\tau=\sigma^{-i}$, which is certainly in any subgroup that $\sigma^i$ is in. So, any subgroup of the rotations is normal.

If $n$ is even, then one can take the normal subgroup of rotations with $n/2$ elements and compute its product with any two element reflection subgroup, and you have another subgroup of order $n$, which has order $2$, and so it's normal. It turns out the only possibilities are $\langle \sigma^2,\tau \rangle$ and $\langle \sigma^2, \sigma\tau \rangle$.

The problem of identifying and proving that they are the only ones is not really short enough to attempt here.

Instead, see this fairly well-written proof [here](http://planetmath.org/dihedralgroupproperties). See corollary 4 for the statement and proof of your problem.